# Кратчайший путь между несколькими точками

Tags: google-maps-api, javascript

Есть ли в гугл-картах готовое решение, которое построит кратчайший маршрут, н-р из 5 точек?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, есть. Google может сам подобрать кратчайшую последовательность между точками маршрута:

> По умолчанию служба маршрутов
> вычисляет маршрут через указанные
> путевые точки в порядке их
> перечисления. Дополнительно можно
> передать optimize:true в качестве
> первого аргумента параметра waypoints,
> чтобы разрешить службе маршрутов
> оптимизировать предоставленный маршрут
> путем выбора более эффективной
> последовательности путевых точек.

Остальное [тут](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=ru).